# Why Detector Processor can not recognition text from camera, android?

Tags: android, ocr

I am trying to use OCR from camera at run time on android device, I found [this example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0)
it is using **com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0** and I download and import the project to android studio 3.1.1 and run it on my android device **SM-J320H** ,the application run but it can't recognition any text.
when I debug the code I notice **detections.getDetectedItems()** always return empty object of **SparseArray**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPVMY.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
        mGraphicOverlay.clear();
        SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
            TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
            OcrGraphic graphic = new OcrGraphic(mGraphicOverlay, item);
            mGraphicOverlay.add(graphic);
        }
    }
```

Check if you did this.